# my list function doesn't work in javascript

Tags: javascript, list, append, appendchild

so i wrote this code that would create a list and then append an input to it on click. really simple. but the problem is it doesn't work and i have no idea why
here is the code:

```
function pushing() {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var inputValue = document.getElementById("inp").value;
  var pushchild = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
  li.appendChild(pushchild);
}

sub.addEventListener("click", pushing);
```

the id `inp` is an input id. thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO!  I recommend all new users visit [ask] for tips on how to write questions that best enable the community to provide assistance.  Can you specify what "doesn't work" means in this context?  Does it get called?  Are there any error messages?  Is there a broken output to the UI or no change whatsoever?  Also, providing a [mcve] is critical to conveying the issue.  I'd recommend making these changes to increase your chance of getting meaningful guidance.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Comment: um, you never append the li to anything.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to the last line of your function. Append your newly created li element to the ul.

```
document.querySelectorAll(‘ul’).appendChild(newCreatedLi);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your list item is never appended to a list element.

```js
// Cache the elements,
// add the button listener,
// & focus on the input
const list = document.querySelector('ul');
const input = document.querySelector('#inp');
const sub = document.querySelector('#sub');
sub.addEventListener('click', pushing);
input.focus();

function pushing() {
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  const text = document.createTextNode(input.value);
  li.appendChild(text);

  // Adding the list item to the list element
  list.appendChild(li);
}
```

```html
<input id="inp" />
<button id="sub">Click</button>
<ul></ul>
```

Comment: first of all im sorry for not typing in the style of the usual site. it will get better throughout the time
and thanks every one to show me the obvious problem.
my list item was never appended to a list element. i just fixed the problem and it works fine. great! thank you

Comment: There is no site style @user17389280. Everyone writes their code differently. I just like to cache my elements up front. Those links to the help section will be useful when using this site in the future, however. It can be a little of a battleground sometimes. Happy coding!